# php mysql table query giving HTTP 500 error if rows in table are very high

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I have below code running in laravel for my flutter app. While code works fine, however I am getting HTTP 500 error many times and this code fails to execute command. I have around 30K rows in 'products' table which is causing HTTP 500 error.
Does total rows in a table affect the execution of code as it fails 5-6 times and works 1-2 times. Is there anything can be done to avoid HTTP 500 error if rows in table are more than 10k-20k

```
 public function updateItem(Request $req){
   
    $results = DB::table('products')->get()->where('id' , $req->input('product_id'));
     foreach($results as $row) {
          $stock_quantity = $row->stock_quantity;
     }
    
    if($stock_quantity >=$req->input('quantity')) {
        
     $affected = DB::table('bag')->where('id', $req->input('id'))->update(['quantity' => $req->input('quantity'), 
            ]
                );
               
                if($affected == 1) {
                $response = array('message'=>"Bag item updated",'result'=>1);
                
                 return $response;
      } else {
        $response = array('message'=>"Error in updating", 'result'=>0);
        return $response;
      }
        
    }else {
        
        $response = array('message'=>"Stock not available", 'result'=>0);
        return $response;
        
    }
    }
```

Comment: MySQL does not throw HTTP errors. Check your server's HTTPD error logs. It sounds like your may be exceeding a php.ini limit of some sort.

Comment: Normally 20-30k rows is nothing when it comes to databases. The problem is more likely the fact that you have `->get()` before the `->where` which means you get all the rows in memory and then you filter the resulting collection in PHP instead of having the database filter them

Comment: i was getting  error : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes). solution of putting ->get after -> where solved it. Thanks @apokryfos